# jQuery Validation Plugin Multiple Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am having some difficulty in using the [jQuery Validator](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugin.  I have a list of checkboxes with *different* `name` attributes and I can't seem to figure out how to ensure that at least one of them has been checked.  Everything that I find on Google seems to only work when the `name` attribute is the same.

Here is some sample code **(updated)**:

```
<ul id="email_lists">
    <li>
        <input name="checkbox1" type="checkbox" /> List 1
    </li>
    <li>
        <input name="checkbox2" type="checkbox" /> List 2
    </li>
    <li>
        <input name="checkbox3" type="checkbox" /> List 3
    </li>
    <li>
        <input name="checkbox4" type="checkbox" /> List 4
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to make sure that at least one of those is checked.  Unfortunately, I **cannot** make the names the same as it is form that submits to a third-party email marketing application and it is expecting specific `name` attributes for these checkboxes.

**Update**

I am aware of how to do this using plain jQuery, but I would prefer to use the [jQuery Validator](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugin since that is how all of the other validation on the page is done.

I can group those checkboxes using jQuery by saying `$('#email_lists li');`, but I'm not really sure how to use something like that and tell the jQuery Validator plugin to use that as a group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you can give the checkboxes a class name (the jQuery needs *something* to work with):

```
<input class="validationGroupOne" name="checkbox1" type="checkbox" />
<input class="validationGroupOne" name="checkbox2" type="checkbox" />
<input class="validationGroupOne" name="checkbox3" type="checkbox" />
<input class="validationGroupOne" name="checkbox4" type="checkbox" />
```

You should be able to plug in the `.validationGroupOne` class-selector in place of the, usual, `name` attribute.

Comment: I can give them a class name or since I actually have them in an unordered list, I could so something along the lines of $('#idOfUL input[type=checkbox]').  Where could I find the documentation on .validationGroupOne?

Comment: @Jared: that was just a random class-name I used; I don't think it has any importance, or relevance, to anything outside of this example. And yeah, presumably you could access them via the `ul` just as easily. I've not worked with this plug-in though, so I'm not 100%.

Comment: Ah gotcha, I thought that was actually a rule or extra method that is part of the jQuery Validation plugin.  I guess my question then is how would I then tell the jQuery Validation plugin to then use that group?  That is where I think my confusion is.

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution :-)

Use:

```
<div id="list">
<input name="chkbox" type="checkbox" />
<input name="chkbox" type="checkbox" />
<input name="chkbox" type="checkbox" />
<input name="chkbox" type="checkbox" />
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="the_real_field_name" />
```

Then in jquery validate plugin block:

```
rules : {
       chkbox: "required"
        },
```

Then store the values as an array into a single hidden field like:

```
function updateInput() {
    var allVals = [];
    $('#list :checked').each(function() {
        allVals.push($(this).val());
    });
    $('#the_real_field_name').val(allVals);
}
$(function() {
    $('#list input').click(updateInput);
    updateInput();
});
```